# how to calculate total execution time for all child processes running simultenously?

Tags: c, fork, child-process, benchmarking

How to calculate the execution time for multiple child processes, which are forked to run in parallel and have the same parent? Is the following code fork the process to run in parallel or they execute serially?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
void forkChildren (int nChildren) {
    int i,j;
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t my_id;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    for (i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            /* error handling here, if needed */
            return;
        }
        if (pid == 0) { 
      /*  printf("I am a child: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());*/
            for(j=0;j<20000000;j++)
            {
                if(j%100==0)
                {
                    my_id = getpid();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
clock_t start,stop;
double elapsed;
start = clock();
    if (argc < 2) {
        forkChildren (2);
    } else {
        forkChildren (atoi (argv[1]));
    }
    stop = clock();
    elapsed = (double)(stop - start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time elapsed in ms: %f", elapsed);
    return 0;
}
```

The previous code generates more than one output execution time, I think for each process separately. the results for the previous code shown below.but I want to calculate the execution time that all the forked process take to execute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to block in parent process until all child processes have terminated :

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
  /* error handling here, if needed */
  return;
}
if (pid == 0) {
  /*  printf("I am a child: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());*/
  for (j = 0; j < 20000000; j++) {
    if (j % 100 == 0) {
      my_id = getpid();
    }
  }
  return;
} else {

  while (pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) {
    if (errno == ECHILD) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The parent will hang in the while loop until no child process is left and then returns. So you calculate total time needed for all children to finish execution.